# Is it possible to combine Html.LabelFor CSS class and text value in MVC Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I was looking for a way to change this combination to a more suited solution, so the input (+hidden) and label are generated from razor.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(s => s.RememberMe, new { @class = "custom-control-input" })
<label class="custom-control-label" for="flyoutRememberMe">
    @Html.Sitecore().DictionaryContent(Dictionary.LoginRememberMeFieldName, true)
</label>
```

This doesn't allow me to change the text value:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(s => s.RememberMe, new { @class = "custom-control-input" })
@Html.LabelFor(s => s.RememberMe, new { @class = "custom-control-label" })
```

And this doesn't allow me to change the CSS class:

```
@Html.LabelFor(s => s.RememberMe, Html.Sitecore().DictionaryContent(Dictionary.LoginRememberMeFieldName, true))
```

Is there a combination of "css class" and "text value" possible in Razor MVC?

**From the LabelExtension.cs**

```
/// <summary>Returns an HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the specified expression using the label text.</summary>
/// <returns>An HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the expression.</returns>
/// <param name="html">The HTML helper instance that this method extends.</param>
/// <param name="expression">An expression that identifies the property to display.</param>
/// <param name="labelText">The label text to display.</param>
/// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the model.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value.</typeparam>
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string labelText);
/// <summary>Returns an HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the specified expression.</summary>
/// <returns>An HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the expression.</returns>
/// <param name="html">The HTML helper instance that this method extends.</param>
/// <param name="expression">An expression that identifies the property to display.</param>
/// <param name="htmlAttributes">An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element.</param>
/// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the model.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">The value.</typeparam>
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes);
/// <summary>Returns an HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the specified expression.</summary>
/// <returns>An HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the expression.</returns>
/// <param name="html">The HTML helper instance that this method extends.</param>
/// <param name="expression">An expression that identifies the property to display.</param>
/// <param name="htmlAttributes">An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element.</param>
/// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the model.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value.</typeparam>
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);
/// <summary>Returns an HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the specified expression.</summary>
/// <returns>An HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the expression.</returns>
/// <param name="html">The HTML helper instance that this method extends.</param>
/// <param name="expression">An expression that identifies the property to display.</param>
/// <param name="labelText">The label text.</param>
/// <param name="htmlAttributes">An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element.</param>
/// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the model.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">The Value.</typeparam>
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string labelText, object htmlAttributes);
/// <summary>Returns an HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the specified expression.</summary>
/// <returns>An HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the expression.</returns>
/// <param name="html">The HTML helper instance that this method extends.</param>
/// <param name="expression">An expression that identifies the property to display.</param>
/// <param name="labelText">The label text to display.</param>
/// <param name="htmlAttributes">An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element.</param>
/// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the model.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value.</typeparam>
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string labelText, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);
```

Comment: You could create a custom `HtmlHelper` extension method that renders all the html

Comment: But the `LabelFor()` method has an overload that accepts the text as the 2nd parameter and `htmlAttributes` as the 3rd parameter

Comment: What does you `DictionaryContent()` return? (I assume its not `string`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your css class as the 3rd parameter for `LabelFor()` function and be sure that your `Sitecore().DictionaryContent` function is giving a string value:

```
@Html.LabelFor(s => s.RememberMe, Html.Sitecore().DictionaryContent(Dictionary.LoginRememberMeFieldName, true).ToString(), new { @class = "yourCSSClass" }))
```

Comment: Odd, visual studio shows an error => {{Argument 3: cannot convert from "<anonymous type: string class>" to bool}} 
I'll give it a try...

Comment: As I said, the error occurs as expected. Perhaps there's an attribute that fills in the text? => `new { @class = "my-css-class", value = "my-dictionary" }`

Comment: Maybe your 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor' version is causing this problem. I tested it in Razor version 3.0.0.0 and it doesn't show an error. What is yours?

Comment: version: 3.0.30128.0, Is it possible this is related to Sitecore CMS?
I'll add the extension options to the question...

Comment: What is the result if you try it with a normal string input? Like: @Html.LabelFor(s => s.RememberMe, "testLabel" , new { @class = "yourCSSClass" }))

Comment: Simply add toString method to my dictionary and it works => `Html.Sitecore().DictionaryContent(Dictionary.LoginRememberMeFieldName, true).ToString()`

Comment: Thanks for the help, if you can elaborate to this in your answer, I'll accept it ^^

Comment: You're welcome. I'll be glad to hear that it works. I will add this to my answer :)